# sidewaystable with 8 coloumns

Tags: longtable, multicolumn, sidewaystable

here is my table but I can't figure out how to arrange 4 more column on the right side.

```
 \begin{sidewaystable}
 \centering
\caption{Realtime forecast RMSEs}
 \label{forecast}
 \begin{tabular}{@{}l
    c
    *{6}{S[table-format=1.6, group-digits=false]}
    S[table-format=-1.6, group-digits=false]
    S[table-format=1.6, group-digits=false]@{}}

\toprule
\multirow{2}[3]{*}{\bfseries Parameters} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{\bfseries $S\&P$ \\ $\boldsymbol{h=2Q}$}} & 
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{\bfseries GDP \\ $\boldsymbol{h=2Q}$}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{\bfseries Unemployment \\ \bfseries $\boldsymbol{h=2Q}$}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{\bfseries house price index \\ \bfseries $\boldsymbol{h=2Q}$}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{\bfseries Inflation \\ \bfseries $\boldsymbol{h=2Q}$}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries RMSE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries RMSE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries RMSE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries RMSE} \\
\midrule
$b_k = 0$ &     &       &        &       &      &       &       &        \\
\hspace{7pt} $\beta$ & 0.097  & 0.009& 0.245 & 0.009 & 0.013 & 0.089 & 0.003& 0.078 \\
\hspace{7pt} $\sigma$ & 0.003  & 0.013 & 0.077& 0.015 & 0.065 & 0.002 & 0.074& 0.000\\
\hspace{7pt} $\theta$ & 0.184  & 0.045 & 0.069 & 0.078 & 0.005 & 0.046 & 0.078 & 0.055 \\
    \hspace{7pt} $\delta$ & 0.165  & 0.036 & 0.078 & 0.004 & 0.063& 0.015 & 0.045 & 0.077\\
\addlinespace
$b_k \neq 0$ &     &       &        &       &      &       &       &        \\
\hspace{7pt} $\beta$ & 0.002  & 0.889 & 0.764 & 0.445 & 0.057 & 0.447 & 0.008 & 0.078 \\
\hspace{7pt} $\sigma$ & 0.001  & 0.446 & 0.003 & 0.096 & 0.065 & 0.047 & 0.005 & 0.054\\
\hspace{7pt} $\theta$ & 0.004  & 0.410 & 0.004 & 0.080 & 0.045 & 0.004 & 0.014& 0.036\\
    \hspace{7pt} $\delta$ & 0.005  & 0.780 & 0.002 & 0.070 & 0.052 & 0.046 & 0.051 & 0.065 \\
\bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
    \end{sidewaystable}
```

However, this is the output:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your `MWE` from `\documentclass{...}` to `\end{document}`

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not very clear. You already have filled 8 columns and have a header for two more, yet undefined columns. Are this means that you like to have two more? Anyway, you just define number of columns which you like to have and add their data in them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}         % new
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{xparse}     % new
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{>{\bfseries}c}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\caption{Realtime forecast RMSEs for $\bm{h=2Q}$}
\label{forecast}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{@{}
             >{$}c< {$}
           *{12}{S[table-format=1.3]}   %   <--
                @{}}
    \toprule
\multirow{2.4}{3em}{\bfseries Para- meter} 
    & \mcc[2]{$\bm{S\&P$}\tnote{a}}    
                 & \mcc[2]{GDP\tnote{b}}         
                              & \mcc[2]{Unemploy.}
                                            & \mcc[2]{HPI\tnote{c}}                  \\  
    \cmidrule(l){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}     \cmidrule(l){6-7} 
    \cmidrule(l){8-9} \cmidrule(l){10-11}   \cmidrule(l){12-13}                    
    & \mcc{Mean} & \mcc{RMSE} & \mcc{Mean} & \mcc{RMSE} & \mcc{Mean} & \mcc{RMSE} 
    & \mcc{Mean} & \mcc{RMSE} & \mcc{Mean} & \mcc{RMSE} & \mcc{Mean} & \mcc{RMSE}   \\
    \midrule
b_k = 0 & \mcc[10]{}                                                                \\
\beta   & 0.097  & 0.009 & 0.245 & 0.009 & 0.013 & 0.089 & 0.003 & 0.078 &  &  &  & \\
\sigma  & 0.003  & 0.013 & 0.077 & 0.015 & 0.065 & 0.002 & 0.074 & 0.000 &  &  &  & \\
\theta  & 0.184  & 0.045 & 0.069 & 0.078 & 0.005 & 0.046 & 0.078 & 0.055 &  &  &  & \\
\delta  & 0.165  & 0.036 & 0.078 & 0.004 & 0.063 & 0.015 & 0.045 & 0.077 &  &  &  & \\
\addlinespace
b_k\neq 0   & \mcc[12]{}                                                            \\
\beta   & 0.002  & 0.889 & 0.764 & 0.445 & 0.057 & 0.447 & 0.008 & 0.078 &  &  &  & \\
\sigma  & 0.001  & 0.446 & 0.003 & 0.096 & 0.065 & 0.047 & 0.005 & 0.054 &  &  &  & \\
\theta  & 0.004  & 0.410 & 0.004 & 0.080 & 0.045 & 0.004 & 0.014 & 0.036 &  &  &  & \\
\delta  & 0.005  & 0.780 & 0.002 & 0.070 & 0.052 & 0.046 & 0.051 & 0.065 &  &  &  & \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]
\item[a] S\&P ...,
\item[b] GDP ...,
\item[c] Hause Price Index.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

In above code I redefine `S` columns, add `threeparttable for use of`tablenotes`macro`\tnote` for explanation of meaning of shorteness in column headers.

Comment: thanks ,but it seems that your code give me another output , is there a missing package or what?

Comment: There is a `\\ ` missing in line 27. It should actally be `& \mcc[2]{HPI\tnote{c}}   \\ `  instead of `& \mcc[2]{HPI\tnote{c}}`.

Comment: @haithem: The "different output" you get is generated by code that produces error messages. If you recieve error messages, do not look at the output but add there messages to your request for clarification. Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: @leandriis, you are right. Incidentally I  didn't upload the last version of code. Now code is corrected.

Comment: @haithem, does  edited answer solve your problem?